# Javascript strike() operation is not working

Tags: javascript

I want to use Js to strike the text, however it cannot be done by using Js.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>

  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      document.getElementsByTagName("p")[0].innerText.strike();

    </script>

  </head>

  <body>

     <p>Version 2.0 is not yet available! now available!</p>

     <p>The strike element is not supported in HTML5. Use CSS instead.</p>

  </body>
</html>
```

I have tried even `innerHTML`, but it is still not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [to be deprecated strike](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/strike) does not work in situ

In general you need to re-assign values and attributes back to their object in JavaScript.

In this case you need to assign the innerHTML the striked text since it is just wrapping in
`<strike></strike>` tags

```js
var par = document.getElementsByTagName("p")[0];
par.innerHTML = par.innerText.strike();
```

```html
<p>Version 2.0 is not yet available! now available!</p>

<p>The strike element is not supported in HTML5. Use CSS instead.</p>
```

Better to use CSS: `text-decoration: line-through;`

```js
var par = document.getElementsByTagName("p")[0];
par.classList.add("strike");
```

```css
.strike { text-decoration: line-through }
```

```html
<p>Version 2.0 is not yet available! now available!</p>

<p>The strike element is not supported in HTML5. Use CSS instead.</p>
```